# Json object within an object issue

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm doing some work with nodeJS and my knowledge of JSON is obviously TOO elementary as I'm failing to read some info. I wonder if anyone can help.

This is a list of item names - each with its own properties. Here's what I'm working with....

```
{
    "moment": {
        "current": "2.13.0",
        "wanted": "2.17.1",
        "latest": "2.17.1",
        "location": "home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/moment"
    },
    "node-red-admin": {
        "current": "0.1.2",
        "wanted": "0.1.3",
        "latest": "0.1.3",
        "location": "home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/node-red-admin"
    }
}
```

So the first item is called moment - and it has 4 attributes - current, wanted,latest and location. The second item is node-red-admin it too has 4 attributes

etc.

So assuming this is sitting in msg.payload...

I want to format the output..

```
var m = "";
msg.payload=JSON.parse(msg.payload);
for (var key in msg.payload)
{
    m += key;
    msg += "<tab>";
    var mm = msg.payload[key];
    m += mm.current;
    m += "<br/>"
}
msg.payload=m;
return msg;
```

All very good - I'm building up the message in m... and getting the names of the items - i.e. "moment", "node-red-admin" etc - but clearly I'm miles out at getting the inner attributes - ie the value of "current" in this example just says I'm talking rubbish.  How do I get to those inner attributes..?

Comment: Do what is done now in the for loop,  just recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Your code getting `current` would be fine, but you're blowing away `msg` before you get there.

```
msg+="<tab>";
```

After that line, `msg` is `"[object Object]<tab>"`, which has no `payload` property, so `msg.payload[key]` throws an error trying to access a property on `undefined`.

You want to leave `msg` and `msg.payload` alone during the loop.

For instance, if you change `msg` in that line to `m`, the end result in `m` is `"moment<tab>2.13.0<br/>node-red-admin<tab>0.1.2<br/>"`:

```js
var msg = {
 payload:
        '{' +
        '    "moment": {' +
        '        "current": "2.13.0",' +
        '        "wanted": "2.17.1",' +
        '        "latest": "2.17.1",' +
        '        "location": "home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/moment"' +
        '    },' +
        '    "node-red-admin": {' +
        '        "current": "0.1.2",' +
        '        "wanted": "0.1.3",' +
        '        "latest": "0.1.3",' +
        '        "location": "home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/node-red-admin"' +
        '    }' +
        '}'
};

var m="";
msg.payload=JSON.parse(msg.payload);
for (var key in msg.payload)
{
    m+=key;
    m+="<tab>";
    var mm=msg.payload[key];
    m+=mm.current;
    m+="<br/>"
}
console.log(m);
```